# How can I put a trait constraint on a type while implementing a trait?

Tags: rust, traits

I have an Iterator that produces Fibonacci numbers. I restricted the type to `u32`, but now I'm struggling to make it generic for any numeric type.

Working, non-generic code:

```
struct Fib {
    value: u32,
    next: u32,
}

impl Fib {
    fn new( a : u32, b : u32 ) -> Fib {
        Fib { value : a, next : b }
    }
}

impl Iterator for Fib {
    type Item = u32;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<u32> {
        let value = self.value;
        let next = self.value + self.next;
        self.value = self.next;
        self.next = next;
        Some( value )
    }
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////

fn main() {

  let fib = Fib::new( 1, 2 );

  let sum = fib.filter( |x| { x % 2 == 0 })
      .take_while( |&x| { x <= 4000000 })
      .fold( 0, |sum, x| { sum + x });

  println!("{}", sum);
}
```

The issue is that the implementation of `Iterator` requires a constraint to `Num`, but I don't know how to express this:

```
 impl <T : Num> Iterator for Fib<T> { ... }
```

Produces:

```
 use of undeclared trait name `Num`
```

And when I try either `use std::num::{Num}` or `use num::traits::{Num}`, I am told that the modules do not exist.

Comment: Uhh... [that trait **doesn't** exist](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/?search=Num). The error message is pretty spot-on here.

Comment: I found it here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/num/num/traits/trait.Num.html
How can I tell which documentation is out of date?

Comment: This is from the num crate, not from stdlib ~> https://crates.io/crates/num

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you want `Fib` to be generic over numeric types, but types that implement the `+` operator. Like so:

```
use std::ops::Add;

struct Fib<N>
where N: Add<Output = N> + Copy {
    value: N,
    next: N,
}

impl<N> Iterator for Fib<N>
where N: Add<Output = N> + Copy {
    type Item = N;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<N> {
        let next = self.value + self.next;
        self.value = self.next;
        self.next = next;
        Some(next)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let fib_seq = Fib {
        value: -1,
        next: 1,
    };

    for thing in fib_seq.take(10) {
        println!("{}", thing);
    }
}
```

`Add` is the trait that allows you to use the `+` operator and produce `Output`. In this case `N` implements the `Add<Output = N>` trait which means `N + N` will produce something of type `N`.

That sounds like it, but when you try to do `self.next + self.value` you are *moving* `value` and `next` out of `self` which causes an error.

You can't get away with not moving the values since the definition of add has this method signature:

```
fn add(self, rhs: RHS) -> Self::Output;
```

`RHS` in `Add`'s case is just `Self`. So in order to restrict `N` it to types that can just be copied with little overhead I added the `Copy` trait as a restriction.

OP mentions an interesting point: Is it possible to alias traits? In short no.
You *could* make a new trait:

```
trait SimpleAdd: Add<Output = Self> + Copy {
}
```

But then you would have to implement that trait for all the types you wanted. I.e. `i32` does not automatically implement `SimpleAdd`. But you can do it with generics if you wanted:

```
impl<N> SimpleAdd for N
where N: Add<Output = N> + Copy {
}
```

So the above two blocks will get you the same thing as a trait alias, but it seems like a hassle.

Comment: Thanks. I had just figured out that I needed to also require `Copy` along with `Num`, but I was still researching to see if that was the correct approach. `Add` is definitely what I want though - I had found a different version of it in the "official" docs that is no longer part of the language, which is annoying.

Comment: Also, I didn't know about the `where` syntax. That's great!

Comment: Requiring `N` to be `Copy` won't be super generic. Sure, you could change that to `Clone` but that would uglify the code. I would probably prefer `where for<'a,'b> &'a N : Add<&'b N, Output = N>` instead. This should still work with built-in types but also support more complicated user-defined types that are neither `Copy` nor cheap to clone (like some BigInt type).

Comment: @sellibitze but then you would have to return borrows of `N` from the `next` method, which I think makes this a streaming iterator, which is hard to do in rust right now.

Comment: You're right. I forgot about that something has to be returned. I guess, this requires one cloning after all.

Comment: @MichaelEden that would explain why I couldn't make this work!

Comment: Is there a way to make an alias for the type parameter context, i.e. `N: Add<Output = N> + Copy`?  In Haskell, the context would be inferred everywhere except the Iterator impl, so I wouldn't have to write it so many times, but it seems I have to write it in full everywhere (including the `new()` constructor etc)

Comment: @MichaelEden: note that [`core::ops::AddAssign`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/ops/trait.AddAssign.html) is available on nightly, allowing to overload `+=`, and `+=` does not require to move its arguments, making it more efficient for BigInt implementations.